# How to create a list of the index and value of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe in python and I am trying to make a list from only the valid values in a column and their index, e.g.

```
index   A    B   C   D
Grade            50  50
Date    50          
Time             50  50
Score   50          
Height       50
```

I want a list that takes the [column,index_name,value] which looks like so

```
[A,Date,50,Score,50]
[B,Height,50]
[C,Grade,50,Time,50]
```

So far what I got is

```
for column in df:
    df.loc[df[column] >= 50]
    matched_list = (df.loc[df[column] >= 50])
    full_list = [column] + list(matched_list.index.values) + [x for x in df[column] if x >= 50]
```

However this gives me this:

```
[A,Date,Score,50.50]
[B,Height,50]
[C,Grade,Time,50,50]
```

Can anyone help and thank you!

Comment: want to use pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it there. You just need to interleave your last two lists to get the desired output. You could accomplish this with one more list comprehension:

```
for column in df:
    df.loc[df[column] >= 50]
    matched_list = (df.loc[df[column] >= 50])
    indices = list(matched_list.index.values)
    values = [x for x in df[column] if x >= 50]
    full_list = [column] + [i for j in zip(indices, values) for i in j]
```

The last line is the one you are interested in. I just assigned your previous two lists to variables to keep the lines relatively short.

Comment: what does the for i in j part in the last line of code doing exactly?

Comment: The i, j in the list comprehension is just a little bit for interleaving values in the zip created from the two lists.

Comment: More specifically, the first j takes each tuple pair from the zip object, and then the second for iterates over each of the two elements in this tuple: i.